# 'NSUnknownKeyException': this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key

Tags: xcode, nsunknownkeyexception

I got this message:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<FirstViewController 0x601b610> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key newCell.'
```

How do I solve it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [This class is not key value coding-compliant for the key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3088059/this-class-is-not-key-value-coding-compliant-for-the-key)

Answer (score 7):

That is generally due to deleting an IB object but forgetting to delete it's links.

IE deleting a UIScrollView but forgetting to delete how it used to link into UIView through an IBOutlet.

Had the same problem earlier today... found the answer here: http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/47036-setvalue-forundefinedkey-class-not-key-value-coding-compliant-key.html

Answer (score 0):

In case that helps someone else, after checking and updating all your links between the views and the matching IBOulet, Cleaning you project can sometimes fix this issue.